# What exactly does the author refer to?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I was looking up a book about choosing refractories (a fire resistant type of brick) for steel industries. In the introduction, the author writes (emphasis mine):

> Why do  you pick the refractory you do? How do you choose? Where do
> you start the selection process?
>
> [...]
>
> The answers to  the first three questions - in a word they are
> COMPLEX.  It is always a balance of competing interests between
> operations, purchasing and the suppliers. The refractory
> engineer/selector is at a crossroads to  decide which is the correct
> material for each application.
>
> The  goal of this book is  not to select refractories for  any
> individual facility  or process or piece of equipment, but instead to
> provide a step by step process for how to do it.
>
> This book will be a guideline, with enough depth to provide a good
> solid basis for material selection, but well short of the depth needed
> to  actually design a material from a refractory manufacturer point of
> view. The first five chapters will be the process described, and the
> next five chapters some principles for key pieces of the steel shop.
>
> **Note that the examples will be for steelmaking only as it makes up
> ~80% of the dollars spent by a steel plant (~50% of the worldwide
> refractory market)**; however, the process can be used in any refractory
> application in any industry.

What exactly does the author mean with the "~80% of dollars spent"? Is it 80% of the total steel plant's expenses? This would really surprise me, since refractories are not *that* expensive (~750$ per ton) and steel plants have huge heating needs.

A friend said that he understands steel plants to be responsible for 80% of the entire refractory revenue. But this doesn't make sense to me. Why would they pay 80% of the revenue for only 50% of product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear.

My first reading was that 80% of dollars spent in a steel plant are spent on steelmaking. But this seems unlikely and irrelevant.

My second thought is that 80% of the money spent on refractories by steel plants is spent on refractories for steel making.  That is relevant, but I wonder what the other 20% is spent on (I read that steel plants are important producers of sulphur, naphtha and ammonia, as by-products, so that may be the explanation)

Your friend might be right.  It may be that steel plants require very high-quality and high-value refractories, so steel plants are 80% of revenue, but only 50% of the product.

The text is unclear.  But also not very important, (if your goal is to understand refractory purchasing decisions) so I suspect most readers would just skip past that line.